# Error in pymongo mapreduce example?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

I was trying to execute the example in "http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.3/examples/map_reduce.html",I got the following error :

> File "map_red.py", line 30, in
>
> if **name** == '**main**': main()
>
> File "map_red.py", line 24, in main
>
> result = db.things.map_reduce(map, reduce )
>
> TypeError: map_reduce() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

So I edited the code to look like this , but i dont see any output(I also replaced "result" with "mr_result" in find() but still there was no output!!)

```
result = db.things.map_reduce(map, reduce,{"out": "mr_results"} )
result_find = db.result.find()
for doc in result_find:
    print doc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the documentation example for the older PyMongo 1.3, but appear to have a more recent version installed.

You can check your PyMongo version with:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.version
'2.2.1+'
```

Expect you want to refer to the current documentation instead:

- [Map/Reduce example](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/map_reduce.html)
- [map_reduce() function](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce)